# Given midterm and finals; select answers which predict overall success

Tags: regression, probability, pca, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

Midway through the course, students' grasp of topics ['category'] gets tested. Same for finals. Like:

```
SID    score_pre    score_post    question   question_category
1      80           90            <omitted>  cat_6
2      60           50            <omitted>  cat_6
1      70           78            <omitted>  cat_5
2      84           95            <omitted>  cat_5
3      86           86            <omitted>  cat_4
1      74           20            <omitted>  cat_4
2      0            100           <omitted>  cat_4
```

or differently

```
Student ID    question category    score midterm    score final
1             6                    80               90            
1             5                    70               78 
1             4                    74               20
2             6                    60               50
2             5                    84               95
2             4                    0                100
3             4                    86               86
```

What approach do I use to show which combination of questions predict success in the course?

[also which combination of categories]

Comment: Is this in turn an assignment?

Comment: No, I was just trying to think of the best way to ask the question. Got some real data from a MOOC that I'm playing with here. Got the format pretty similar to what I showed above.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting topic. But, I find it difficult to understand this question. For instance explain the variables that you put in the table, and spend some more on the concept of the question in relation to those variables. 'predict success in the course' that is too much 'out of the blue'.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Let's say they need 50% for a pass, 70% for credit, 80% for distinction and 85% for high distinction. Here if they get ¾ of the answers correct, they get a credit. Midterm is worth 50% of course, final is worth the other ½. Another interesting question for the model to answer, is: **are midterm answers sufficient to predict failure/success in the whole course?**

Comment: I agree with @Martijn that the data given aren't fully clear and further if your real data are "pretty similar" we need to know what differs. A guess: regress final against mid-term using question as an extra categorical predictor. If all students doing the midterms all answered the same questions, then it's simpler.

Comment: @NickCox Yes: all students doing the midterms all answered the same questions. Happy to simplify things further, say all scores are either `1` or `0`. Example: `{question: "Is Apple a fruit?", score: 1, question_category: "Fruit"}`. I'm developing in Pandas and MySQL dialect SQL if that's of note.

Comment: This sounds like a standard regression problem on that information. Final result as a function of scores for midterm questions.

Comment: @AT, I have edited your question adding a table with different descriptors and eliminated the useless column (the question with only omitted entries), which people might better understand. Let me know if you agree whether this is an improvement. I have only added a table and did not remove the other one, which you may do yourself if you wish (because I do not like to change others people data), or you can remove my edits alltogether.

Comment: Regarding your question some exploratory analysis might be useful, in addition to Nicks' comment that a regression or lda would work. Based on exploratory analysis (such as pca and cluster analysis) you might possibly identify different types of students. I believe it is more useful to use such clusters or principle component axes, indicating some underlying structure, rather than a set of of regression coefficients (the regression is also tricky since you can do it in different ways, e.g. predict 'success versus improvement on total result versus individual categories').

Comment: My last comment is also where providing a clear answer starts to become difficult.  There are many ways to approach this problem, and a better idea of the data would make the creation of a more specific and better answer more easy (if it is possible at all).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Sure, your edits are mostly fine. My actual data is close enough to this, though the question_category are actual topic strings (no numbers).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings But yeah clustering the data together is really the entire problem; no? - Because if I know what data to cluster together than I also know what the clusters which influence the score are [i.e.: the "principal components"; PCA]. - Which is exactly what I'm looking for? - Or do I need to combine that with other techniques to get the answer I'm looking for? - Add as an answer maybe

Comment: @AT, my edit is how a stranger reads your question. I changed it this way in order to make the question more intuitive, and most importantly faster to read, for people that come across here. I stripped the 'cat_' piece because it seemed superfluous (it can still be a string, or maybe you mean categorical variable, even if there is a number). If this was not correct then you have to re-edit it, but also explain why, explain what this 'cat_' means.

Comment: Me answering your question is at this moment stuck at having an unclear idea of the data and it's structure and is only an answer as 'pca, then cluster analysis, then linear discriminant analysis using categories found with pca and cluster analysis'.

Comment: `cat` as in question category/topic, e.g.: "Fruit". Actually I'm now thinking t-test for each question and ANOVA + Tukey for differences between questions with student as an independent variable. Maybe ANCOVA also…